# Did I have a missing module in python?

Tags: python

I learned how to program AI in python but when I run it in cmd I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5xQQ.png). Someone told me that I may have a missing module.

This is my code by the way:

```
import cv2

imagePath = "apollo.jpg"
cascadeClassifierPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"

cascadeClassifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadeClassifierPath)

image = cv2.imread(imagePath)

grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

detectedFaces = cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(grayImage)

for(x,y,width,height) in detectedFaces:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+width, y+height), (0,255,0),5)

cv2.imwrite('resultat.jpg', image)
```

I use visual studio code.

Comment: Did you go to the url mentioned in the error message?

Comment: @John Gordon No, I will

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is due to numpy lower version once update the numpy and retry

```py
pip install numpy --upgrade --ignore-installed
```